# Angular 2+ having a master import file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have difference files with data like this:

```
export const config1 = { stuff here }
export const config2 = { other stuff here }
export const config3 = { other stuff here }
```

Then I import them:

```
import { config1 } from 'some path';
import { config2 } from 'some path';
import { config2 } from 'some path';
```

What I what to do is to have like an index file that has all the imports so I just import 1?

So instead of the above I just need to do

```
import { whatever } from 'path'
```

Then I use it like:

```
whatever.config1....
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file e.g. `configs.ts` and export from that like:

```
export * from 'some path for config1';
export * from 'some path for config2';
export * from 'some path for config3';
```

Then you can import from this one file:

```
import { config1, config2, config3, whatever_else } from './path/to/configs';
```